# How to handle price dynamic

Tags: factory, cart, sap-commerce-cloud, price

We have requirement to handle price dynamic (referring external system).
We would like to know, what is the best way to handle dynamic pricing among below :

Approach 1 :

Creating Price factory extension and overriding getBasePrice() method of customPricefactoryManager. Please confirm if it uses jalo layer.

Approach 2 :

In DefaultSLFindPriceStrategy we can customize getBasePrice() method.

If any other way too, please lets know.

We would like to know which approach can help to handle prices in addtocart operation, checkout and product page details pricing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good getting price in another system with integration online. ERP system used by few sales people but ecommerce site can be used by hundred customer in same time. ERP cannot be handle huge amount of connections. I prefer pushing price from ERP not pulling them from hybris side. On the other hand customer will be hate changing price while surfing between hybris pages. You need to plan correct time for updating price and re-calculating existing carts.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely that you would need to override the above classes to get dynamic prices.
Hybris already provides OTB functionality to get prices for different-

1. Users
2. User groups
3. Currencies
4. Time range

If you are trying to get different prices based on above criterions then you can simply use the OTB `price row model`.
Getting dynamic prices on different pages has many caveats-

1. The price on different pages i.e. Homepage, PDP, Cart, Checkout,
   etc. might show different values confusing the customer.
2. It cannot
   be indexed so the PLP page will almost always show a different price
   value.